# не могу понять в чём ошибка

Tags: c, сортировка

Напишите программу, которая будет сортировать массив из 30 элементов типа int, случайно выбранных из диапазона.
От 0 до 8. Печать содержимого массива до и после сортировки.(Используя сортировку подсчётом)

```
#define SIZE 30

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE],i;

    srand(time(0));

    printf("Your array: ");
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        array[i]=rand()%9;
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }

    countsort(array);

    printf("\nSorted array:");
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void countsort(int a[])
{
    int i;

    int output[sizeof(a)];

    int count[SIZE+1];

    for(i =0; i<SIZE+1;i++){
        count[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0;a[i];++i){
        ++count[a[i]];
    }

    for(i=1;i<=SIZE;++i){
        count[i] +=count[i-1];
        --count[a[i]];
    }

    for (i = sizeof(a)-1; i>=0; --i)
    {
        output[count[a[i]]-1] = a[i];
        --count[a[i]];
    }

    for(i=0;a[i];++i){
        a[i]=output[i];
    }





}
```

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что здесь есть ошибка?

Comment: Зачем count размера `SIZE` (это не вредит, только говорит о некотором недопонимании)? Чему равно `sizeof(a)`?

Comment: В чем ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, у вас несколько ошибок при передаче - например,

```
int output[sizeof(a)];
```

здесь в `sizeof(a)` вы получите только размер указателя, к которому приведется при передаче `a`.

Сортировка вообще непонятна.

Есть и другие, просто сейчас детально расписывать нет времени.

Вобщем, смотрите, какой должна быть сортировка:

```
void countsort(int a[], int n)
{

    int i,j,k, count [9] = { 0 };

    for(i=0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        ++count[a[i]];
    }

    j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i< 9; ++i)
    {
        if (count[i])
            for(k = 0; k < count[i]; ++k)
                a[j++] = i;
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста, чтоб меня совесть не мучила :) - разберитесь, как это работает. И еще - 9 лучше сделать переменной, макросом - но не прошивать в программе намертво.

Вот весь код: https://ideone.com/cY7anK